# React Leaflet weird behavior : trigger the onclick event on the map when I delete a marker from a button in a marker popup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-typescript

I have a problem that is: when I click on "delete" on a popup, it deletes my marker BUT it also create a new marker on the map, where I just clicked (the delete button). I've been struggling with it for hours now as I can't find any example that can feat a react-typescript usage of react-leaflet.

You can find two comments in the code to see where is the problem.

`code`

```
import { Marker, Popup, useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-admin';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import L, { LatLngExpression } from 'leaflet';
import * as React from 'react';

type NewMarkerType = {
    pos: LatLngExpression;
    index: number;
};

const NewMarkerContent = ({
    element,
    index,
    setMarkerData,
}: {
    element: NewMarkerType;
    index: number;
    setMarkerData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<NewMarkerType[]>>;
}) => {
    const greenIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl:
            'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|2ecc71&chf=a,s,ee00FFFF',
    });
    const handleDeleteClick = (index: number) => {
        // here i delete the marker and it trigger the onclick event of the map afterward :'(
        setMarkerData((current: NewMarkerType[]) =>
            current.filter((marker) => marker.index != index),
        );
    };
    const markerRef = React.useRef(null);

    const eventHandlers = useMemo(
        () => ({
            dragend() {
                console.log('dragen');
                const marker: any = markerRef.current;
                if (marker != null) {
                    console.log(marker.getLatLng().toString());
                }
            },
        }),
        [],
    );

    return (
        <Marker
            key={index}
            position={element.pos}
            interactive={true}
            icon={greenIcon}
            draggable={true}
            ref={markerRef}
            eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
        >
            <Popup>
                <Box>
                    {element.pos.toString()}
                    {element.index.toString()}
                    <Button onClick={() => handleDeleteClick(element.index)}>
                        <>DELETE</>
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
    );
};

const NewMarker = () => {
    const [markerData, setMarkerData] = useState<Array<NewMarkerType>>([]);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    useMapEvents({
        click(e) {
            console.log('click');
            // this event is triggered by the delete button click.
            if (markerData) {
                const newMarker: NewMarkerType = {
                    pos: L.latLng(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng),
                    index: index,
                };
                setIndex(index + 1);
                setMarkerData((result) => [...result, newMarker]);
            }
            return null;
        },
    });

    return markerData ? (
        <div>
            {markerData.map((element: NewMarkerType, index: number) => (
                <NewMarkerContent
                    element={element}
                    index={index}
                    setMarkerData={setMarkerData}
                    key={index}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    ) : null;
};

export default NewMarker;
```

`code`

I use useMapEvents hook to use the event but I tried other solution and it doesnt seem to be working. I may have just miss something but I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `stopPropagation()`. If that does not work you could try `preventDefault()`

```js
<Button
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    handleDeleteClick(element.index);
  }}
>
  <>DELETE</>
</Button>;
```